# How to reduce Django package size to use in AWS lambda?

Tags: django, aws-lambda

My tech stack is Django, Zappa, AWS lambda(+ API gateway, cloudwatch, more....).

The maximum size of a function code package for `AWS lambda` is `50MB`.

But my package size is `47MB`.

How can I reduce the package size?

Comment: Serve Static and media from S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to figure out what exactly is taking up so much space. Run `zappa package` and inspect the resulting ZIP file. Add anything that's not necessary to the `exclude` list in in your `zappa_settings`. Note that this functionality is somewhat limited in what it can exclude; see [this article](https://ianwhitestone.work/zappa-zip-callbacks/) how to add a `regex_excludes` option that can remove more files via regex matching.

The biggest thing though is probably going to be static assets. Serve them from S3 instead of through your Lambda Django server. The [django-s3-storage](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage) package is very useful. Install it, and configure it in your `settings.py` something like this:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage'
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC = os.environ['STATIC_BUCKET']
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN', f'{AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC}.s3.amazonaws.com')
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/'
```

(I'm using environment variables from the Zappa settings file to customise this per stage, you can configure this however you want.)

Then after deploying to Lambda, run another command to deploy your static files:

```
$ zappa update
$ ./manage.py collectstatic
```

Make sure the static files are *excluded* from the Lambda package as described above. With a combination of these techniques, you should be able to get your package size down; my deployments are currently around 25 MB in size.